# Firefox doesn't recognize profile when mounting using fstab

Tags: partition, firefox, fstab, ntfs

I recently did a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop.
It has an ntfs partition with all my documents and stuff that I might want to use on Windows as well.
When I did the reinstall I forgot to backup the fstab entry that automatically mounted the ntfs partition.

In /etc/fstab I set the uid and guid. I checked this and it seems to work correctly. But when I start firefox (which uses the profile from the ntfs partition) it complains that it can't reach the profile.

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

If I don't use fstab and mount the partition by hand using the gui file explorer, everything works fine.

I know it's possible to mount so that firefox can recognize it because that's what I previously did, but I'm now stuck.

The fstab entry looks like this:

```
UUID=13FBF8751719184A /media/user/files ntfs defaults,rw,exec,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,nofail 0 2
```

When I check it using:

```
ls -la /media/user
```

It shows me the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 user user 28672 mrt 21 12:43 files
```

The specific setting it's trying to load are in `/media/user/files/sharedSettings/firefox`.
This directory has the same permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 24576 mrt 21 14:02 firefox
```

mount returns the following:

```
/dev/sda7 on /media/user/files type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
```

A normal user can read and write normally to the partition, but for some reason firefox still complains about the profile not being accessible.
Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT:
I noticed that `mount` returns `user_id=0` and `group_id=0` while I clearly set those to 1000. Could this possibly the problem?
This is what mount returns after manually mounting the partition:

```
/dev/sda7 on /media/user/Files type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Could it have to do with the `uhelper=udisks2` thing?
How would I add this into the fstab?
The manual page doesn't notice this option.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Where is the profile stored? What permissions does it have? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `gid=1000` rather than `guid=1000`?

Comment: Ah, yes. I'll change that.

Comment: So what does `mount` show if you mount using the gui?

Comment: We need to see the permissions of the profile directory under `/media/user/files/sharedSettings/firefox`. Also, how are you pointing firefox to that, non-standard, location?

Comment: Sorry for the somewhat late update, I tried a few things. I point to the non-standard location by changing a few values in `/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`. This works correctly, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /dev/sda7 on /media/user/files
>
> /dev/sda7 on /media/user/Files

`files` and `Files` are two different paths.  Because the directory `/media/user` is in a native *nix filesystem.  Filenames here are not interpreted e.g. as case-insensitive.  They are simply strings of octets which do not contain `NUL` (0) or ASCII `/`.

Comment: -_- I'm such an idiot...